# dynamic message-mapping for websockets in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-4

I want to develop a small chat with springs new websocket/stomp support.
I guess i cannot use something like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/connect/{roomId}")
@SendTo("/topic/newMessage")
public String connectToChatRoom(@PathVariable String roomId, Principal p) {
    return getTimestamp() + " " + p.getName() + " connected to the room.";
}
```

What are my options for dynamic mapping here? As a client i want to subscribe only to the room I'm in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to use @DestinationVariable instead of @PathVariable

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `@MessageMapping` annotation (javaadoc) and the reference docs both list all supported arguments and return value types.